# uplodify status div get replaced if uploaded same file twice

Tags: c#, jquery, uploadify

i used uplodify to upload multiple files... i have shown the status for each files like in the demo.. but while uploading a large file (>5mb) at that time if i upload that same files again.  the status div for the particular div get replaced..with failure message..
i hope same id is generated at that time which replaces the div with failure message... but how can i handle this error.... is its possible to get a unique id then new div will be generated to show the failed message that is what i needed... pls help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the browse button then when the files are all uploaded display it. it works for me...